# How to run JHipster UAA with docker?

Tags: docker, jhipster, jhipster-registry, jdl, jhipster-gateway

I've generated an application with this JDL

```
deployment {
  deploymentType docker-compose
  appsFolders [gateway, uaa]
  dockerRepositoryName "10.1.10.58:5000"
}

application {
  config {
    baseName uaa
    applicationType uaa,
  }
}

application {
  config {
    baseName gateway
    applicationType gateway,
    packageName com.rps.png,
    authenticationType uaa,
    uaaBaseName "uaa",
  }
}
```

Imported with JHipster, built the docker images and run `docker-compose up`. The application starts but the UAA fails to register to the JHipster registry.

```
----------------------------------------------------------
    Application 'uaa' is running! Access URLs:
    Local:      http://localhost:9999/
    External:   http://172.18.0.4:9999/
    Profile(s):     [prod, swagger]
----------------------------------------------------------
```

No connection with the JHipster registry. Am I missing something on my JDL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current default for `serviceDiscoveryType` for JDL-generated UAA apps is `none` ([related code](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-core/blob/4aa2737d07c5a94a20ee38c391ac74444595ae6a/lib/core/jhipster/default_application_options.js#L169)), you can verify this by looking at the `.yo-rc.json` file generated in the UAA app folder.  This is a difference between the JHipster prompt defaults and JDL defaults, an issue can be opened about this on the [jhipster-core](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-core/) Github.

The simple fix is to set `serviceDiscoveryType eureka` in the UAA app JDL configuration.